# Extends ContainerRequestFilter / ContainerResponseFilter throws class not found exception in JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am creating a REST API authentication server with maven

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.aerogear.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-html5-mobile-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.3.CR6 -Denterprise=true
```

here is my RequestFilter:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import duy.hw4.rest.HTTPHeaderName;
import duy.hw4.service.UserAuthenticator;

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RESTRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RESTRequestFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) throws IOException {

        String path = requestCtx.getUriInfo().getPath();
        log.info("Filtering request path: " + path);

        // IMPORTANT!!! First, Acknowledge any pre-flight test from browsers for this case before validating the headers (CORS stuff)
        if (requestCtx.getRequest().getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            requestCtx.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build());

            return;
        }

        // Then check is the service key exists and is valid.
        UserAuthenticator authenticator = UserAuthenticator.getInstance();
        String serviceKey = requestCtx.getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderName.SERVICE_KEY);

        if (!authenticator.isServiceKeyValid(serviceKey)) {
            // Kick anyone without a valid service key
            requestCtx.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());

            return;
        }

        // For any other methods besides login, the authToken must be verified
        if (!path.startsWith("/moneymanager/login/")) {
            String authToken = requestCtx.getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderName.AUTH_TOKEN);

            // if it isn't valid, just kick them out.
            if (!authenticator.isAuthTokenValid(serviceKey, authToken)) {
                requestCtx.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start server and call web-service, I get below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher
```

After searching, I add provided scope to resteasy-jaxrs dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And when start server again, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter from [Module "deployment.moneymanager.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 24 more
```

Can somebody help me!

Comment: I'm not sure the process of disabling the JAX-RS 1.x module in JBoss, but that's what you probably need to do to make JAX-RS 2.0 work. You can probably find a solution with some searching. Another thing, the scope should not be provided, as it _is not_ provided by the server. The server has a 2.3.x version (which is JAX-RS 1.x)

Comment: I would probably search "upgrading Resteasy to 3.x in JBoss", rather than "disabling", though it does consist of disabling. But a full upgrade example might give a more descriptive solution on the entire process.

Comment: Or if it's an option, use Wildfly, which uses Resteasy 3.x already.

Comment: Server runs without error, thank you, but if I remove provided scope, I will get the exception mentioned above